# Rounded images css

Tags: css

This line of code loads a link with an image above it.

```
<li class="post-nav-wrap">
    <?php
        $prevPost = get_previous_post(true);
        if($prevPost) {
            $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(100,100) );
        }
        previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail  %title", TRUE);
    ?>
</li>
```

I called the image within css with:

```
.post-nav-wrap img {
    width: auto;
    height:110px;
}
```

what I want is the images to be completely rounded. I know how to do this with a image the size of a cube. (like both height and width the same) but this image is a rectangle (265px by 110px). Is is possible to make it completely rounded within css?

Comment: Please don't tag questions with php / wordpress if the issue / question is not related to them.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I thought because it is in wordpress. But I see it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Don't sweat it, my comment was not meant as rude / offensive, simply to inform you of it :)

Comment: @Epodax The solution required altering the PHP and was WordPress related in a sense. The tags were correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
img {
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=265%C3%97110&w=265&h=110" />
```

And incase you meant create a circle from the image:

Add a wrapper to the image and add the border radius to that. Hide the overflow and position the image into the center.

```css
.circle-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
img {
  width: auto;
  height:110px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-wrapper">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=265%C3%97110&w=265&h=110" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great answer! The last one is the one I need. But I am not able to split the image from the text. So the text would be in the same div if I use the wrapper.

Comment: @Kas can you try adding `$prevthumbnail = '<div class="circle-wrapper">' . $prevthumbnail . '</div>` below the first time you define it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
div { 
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/vNh8t/177/)

[**More examples**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/)

Comment: WordPress is returning an `<img>` element, unless you alter the PHP you can't use background-image.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved pretty straight forward->>
Just add a class to your image->>

```css
.rounded {
  flex: none;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```